# Access to meta-data of liferay structure and template with velocity

Tags: xpath, liferay, velocity

I want to read the CDATA "Testlabel" from the entry node in a structure containing this:

```
<dynamic-element fieldNamespace="ddm" indexType="keyword" localizable="true" name="Label_Tag" readOnly="false" repeatable="false" required="false" showLabel="true" type="ddm-separator" width="">
    <meta-data locale="nl_NL">
        <entry name="label">
            <![CDATA[Testlabel]]>
        </entry>
        <entry name="predefinedValue">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </entry>
        <entry name="tip">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </entry>
        <entry name="style">
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </entry>
    </meta-data>
</dynamic-element>
```

In the Application Display Template for an AssetPublisher, I used:

```
#foreach ( $entry in $entries )
    #set ( $renderer = $entry.getAssetRenderer() )
    #set ( $className = $renderer.getClassName() )

    #if ( $className == "com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle" )

        ## read article properties
        #set ( $article = $renderer.getArticle() )

        ## read webcontent as xml
        #set ( $document = $saxReaderUtil.read($article.getContent()) )
        #set ( $rootElement = $document.getRootElement() )

        ## read general elements from webcontent
        #set ( $xPathSelector = $saxReaderUtil.createXPath("dynamic-element[@name='Label_Tag']/meta-data/entry[@name='label']") )
        #set ( $strLabel = $xPathSelector.selectSingleNode($rootElement).getText() )

$ xPathSelector $xPathSelector<br>
$ strLabel $strLabel <br>

    #end
#end
```

which does not work, it prints:

```
$ xPathSelector [XPath: dynamic-element[@name='Label']/meta-data/entry[@name='label']]
$ strLabel $strLabel
```

$strLabel is not filled. What's is wrong?

Comment: @Olaf Kock, changed $Label to $Label_Tag and $label to $strLabel, but that did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You're XPath expression is correct; when applying it to your sample using `xmllint` I get the following result:

```
> xmllint -xpath "dynamic-element[@name='Label_Tag']/meta-data/entry[@name='label']" ~/test.xml
<entry name="label">
    <![CDATA[Testlabel]]>
</entry>
```

Maybe adding `text()` to your XPath query might help:

```
> xmllint -xpath "dynamic-element[@name='Label_Tag']/meta-data/entry[@name='label']/text()" ~/test.xml
<![CDATA[Testlabel]]>
```